# Integration question involving Area and f(t)

Tags: integration

Well I am doing a question and a link of the image is provided here:

[image]

I am wondering about my answers for a few parts.

$\textbf{Part A:}$ Can you just check if I'm correct on these

$$F(0)= 0$$
$$F(2)= 8$$
$$F(4)= 12$$
$$F(6)= 16$$
$$F(10)= 24$$

$\textbf{Part B:}$ Can you just check if I'm correct on this

Minimum at $y=-4$, $x=6$, and local maximum from $x[0,2]$ at $y = 4$.

$\textbf{Part C:}$ I'm not sure about this

I think $F$ is increasing from $(0,4)$ and decreasing from $(4,10)$. Is this right?

Part B: no idea, help please?

Comment: Panthy you kinda want to start using [MathJaX](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on your posts in the future. You also want to ask just one question per post. Although you may get responses here, this is not a homework solution verification site. We want one quality question that inspires quality answers. It helps if they are typeset nicely, images of text that you can type are not so ideal, and in general, I wish you the best of fortune in your studies.

Comment: I simply thought this was a site I could use to ask questions and answer questions that people have. I didn't know it had a quality requirement. Sorry, I guess.

Comment: Panthy I appreciate your thought. In fact one would think that a site specifically defined as a Q&A site would be precisely what you describe. As it turns out, this is a finicky place. I would be remiss if I did not point you toward [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). I a not trying to pick on you, I just want to get you in to the community in a most welcome way.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I will definitely take it into consideration. I was always too lazy to use MathJax since I'm not entierly sure on how to use it, but if it makes the community happier I will start using it. But as for my question itself, I believe asking those are fine. I simply have a doubt on my answers and need some reaffirmation on them.

Comment: Panthy I share your thoughts. Again, best of luck with your studies.

Comment: Again, another homework!

Comment: @Panthy Why don't you ask your instructor/ fellow students instead?

Comment: Because I am doing an independent study without an instructor/students since this is summer and I am sitting at home :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part A: 
$$F(0) = 0$$ $$F(2) = 8$$ $$F(4) = 12$$ $$F(6) = 8$$ $$F(10) = 0$$
because $F$ below the $x$-line has to be calculated negative.

Part B: local maximum is at $x=4$ and local minimums are at $x=0$ and $x=10$

Part C: Your are right. It's increasing for $x(0,4)$ and decreasing for $x(4,10)$

Part D: If we look at the graph we know that:

$$f(x) = 4 \ ,\ x\in(0,2)$$ 
$$f(x) = -2x + 4 \ ,\ x\in(2,6)$$ 
$$f(x) = x - 4 \ ,\ x\in(6,10)$$

So if we integrate $f$ we get:

$$F(x) = 4x \ ,\ x\in(0,2)$$ 
$$F(x) = -x^2 + 4x \ ,\ x\in(2,6)$$ 
$$F(x) = \dfrac{x^2}{2} - 4x \ ,\ x\in(6,10)$$

I think you should be able to draw the graph with this information, but don't forget that f.e. for $F(4)$ don't calculate $-4^2 +4*4$ but $-2^2 + 4*2$ because these formulas are shifted as if they started at $(0,0)$

If you have any further questions feel free to ask.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: thank you, will wait for part D

Comment: This should be accurate. If you calculate f.e. $F(8)$ as $F(2)$ you should get the value on how much it has changed since the value at $x=6$. With this you should be easily able to draw the chart.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, Jan. Just as a matter of notation, I think it is better to write '$f(x) = 4$ for $x \in [0,2]$' instead of '$f(0,2) = 4$' and so on.

Comment: @Shai Yeah that's true. I'm always kind of sloppy with the notation

Answer (score 2):

To **sketch** the function, note that

- On $[0,2],$ $f$ is constant and so its integral will be of the form $kx,$ and the graph of $F$ will be a straight line between $(0,0)$ and $(2,8)$ (you have already shown that $F(0) = 0$ and $F(2) = 8$).
- On $[2,6]$, $f$ is of the form $cx+d$ for negative $c$ and so the integral of $f$ will be a quadratic, and so the graph of $F$ will be a downward-facing parabola taking its maximum at $x=4.$ It will also be symmetrical on the interval $[2,6].$
- On $[6,10]$, $f$ is of the form $ax + b$ for positive $a,$ and so $f$ will be an upwards-facing parabola taking its minimum value at $x=10.$ You will only see the decreasing part of this parabola (we don't know what $f$ does after $x=10$).
- Finally, your pen should never come away from the page. There is a technical reason for this (functions $F$ of this form are always continuous) but it can also be justified intuitively by thinking about how the area of the shape under $f$ changes as $f$ increases.